# On the click of an id, another class needs to appear and it should get hidden on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a menu, and with or without jQuery, when I press an image, the menu should appear from nowhere. On the second click of the image, which acts as the button, it should be hidden back.

It would be better if there is any way, when clicking on the button, the class of a div should be changed to another div.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it has image, menu that show/hide at the click of image

```js
function c() {
  $("#m").toggle();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://rental-1.com/n.jpg" onclick="return c();" id="im" width="100px" />
<ul id="m" style="display:none;">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. It did work. Thanks very much.